# How to set Locale on GSON (for decimal number separators)

Tags: locale, gson, decimalformat

I know you can set date formatting, but how do you set other locale specific stuff like decimal number formatting? (I mean comma vs. dot)

Comment: Please, can you post an example of the desired format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: you don't.

You seem to be somewhat confusing the textual representation of a number and an actual numeric value.

While JSON is a text-based data interchange format, a number (vs. a string) in JSON is a numeric value and is not affected by locale. [Section 2.4 of the JSON specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) provides the specific definition (emphasis mine):

> 2.4.  Numbers
>
> The representation of numbers is similar to that used in most
>   programming languages.  A number contains an integer component that
>   may be prefixed with an optional minus sign, which may be followed by 
>   a fraction part and/or an exponent part.
>
> Octal and hex forms are not allowed.  Leading zeros are not
>   allowed.
>
> **A fraction part is a decimal point followed by one or more digits.**
>
> An exponent part begins with the letter E in upper or lowercase,
>   which may be followed by a plus or minus sign.  The E and optional
>   sign are followed by one or more digits.
>
> Numeric values that cannot be represented as sequences of digits
>   (such as Infinity and NaN) are not permitted.

Given the above, something such as `{"my_double":3,2}` is not valid JSON. `{"my_double":3.2}` is.

When parsing JSON, a parser is going to store numbers to a primitive data type (`int` or `double`). Your locale will then display those properly using the normal methods for converting them to strings; `Integer.toString(myInt)`,`String.valueOf(myDouble)`, etc.