# How to get JAX-RS (Jersey) to use a specific Locale when parsing url parameters and JSON? (Ideally inferred from the "Accept-Language" header)

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, locale, http-accept-language, decimalformat

To be more specific, right now I'm having a problem with the separator on decimal numbers (comma vs dot): If the wrong separator comes in a url parameter the webservice returns 404. But I'd like to find a proper solution that will handle the JSON reading/writing as well.

**Note:**
I've tried the answer in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944025/how-do-i-i18n-jax-rs-jersey-jaxb-annotated-responses) but it references classes I don't have in my Jersey jars (If, QuantityXmlAdapter and NumberPersonalizedXmlAdapter) and I can't find a clue about them on Google.

Comment: Did you mean that the value is in the query stream (a `GET` request, in other words, a `@QueryParam`).

Comment: Yes, this first problem I had was on a "@QueryParam" but I should probably solve this also for "@PathParam" and JSON.

Comment: Which version of JAX-RS and/or the version and application server that you are using?

Comment: As @Brian Roach pointed in my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451670/how-to-set-locale-on-gson-for-decimal-number-separators?noredirect=1#comment28861334_19451670), I'm confusing textual representation of a decimal and float/double literals. Locale doesn't affect the later. I'm fixing the client side so it doesn't send parameters in a Locale specific format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your questions as this.

### Your method

```
@GET
@Path('/resource/{decimal}')
public Response getResoureWithDecimal(@PathParam("decimal") double decimal)
```

### Your request

```
GET /resource/1,2
```

Clearly, `1,2` is not a Java `double` and JAX-RS has no way to convert it to one.

### Possible solution

Use a `String` as the parameter type and convert it with your own converter.

```
@GET
@Path('/resource/{decimal}')
public Response getResoureWithDecimal(@PathParam("decimal") String decimal) {
  double decimalAsDouble = convertStringWithCommaToDouble(decimal);
  // ...
}
```

The implementation of `convertStringWithCommaToDouble(String)` is up to you.